# Como trabalhar com uma instância de DateTime sem a informação das horas

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, testes

Meus testes vinham passando com sucesso, quando "por mágica" um deles começou a falhar:

```
var data1 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
...processos
...processos
var data1 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
Assert.Throws<DataException>(() =>
                p.ChecarDatas(data1, data1));
```

---

```
public static void EnsureDateIsGreaterOrEqualThan(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string errorMessage)
{
    if (startDate <= endDate)
        throw new Exception(errorMessage);
}
```

Mesmo as duas datas sendo "iguais" o teste começou a falhar misteriosamente. Após `debugar`, notei que havia diferença de milésimos de segundo o que fazia o teste falhar (só então notei que o comportamento não era estranho).

Isso tudo para perguntar:

1. Qual a melhor prática para trabalhar com data "pura" sem informação de horário?
2. `DateTime` (com data/hora) é útil em algum caso de comparação de datas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Qual a melhor prática para trabalhar com data "pura" sem informação de horário?

Você pode utilizar a propriedade [`DateTime.Date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx) caso já tenha uma instância da classe `DateTime`. Ela retorna uma instância de `DateTime` com hora sempre igual a 00:00:00.

Você também pode utilizar a propriedade estática [`DateTime.Today`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today(v=vs.110).aspx) para obter a data atual com as horas sempre iguais a 00:00:00. Note que também existe a propriedade [`DateTime.Now`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx) que funciona como a DateTime.Today, mas retorna a hora atual normalmente.

> DateTime (com data/hora) é útil em algum caso de comparação de datas?

Isso vai depender muito de como a datas serão utilizadas na sua aplicação. Se você estiver montando uma aplicação de CMS, como um blog por exemplo, você irá querer saber quando uma postagem foi publicada com uma informação precisa que contenha a hora também.

Answer (score 4):

Até é possível ter um tipo só com a data, mas não é necessário, basta ter o horário zerado. Isto pode ser construído manualmente ou se for pegar de algum lugar externo, tem que garantir que ele seja zerado. Quando vai pegar a data do sistema, então pegue só a data e não a hora. O `DateTime.Now` pega a hora de agora. O [`DateTime.Today`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.today?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_Today) pega a data de hoje.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/mLLWxv). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XwqPIn). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/JustDate.cs).